# Menu with rounded corners?

Tags: c#, wpf, menu

I tried to make a Menu with rounded corners, but I failed. I made an Aero Glass Style for my Application, but with this Style, its sometimes hard to read the Text in the Menu. So I wanted to add a semi-transparent background to the Menu. But it looks quite ugly. The Menu background should look like the one from Firefox or Thunderbird (With "Menu Bar" Enabled). Is there a way to do this?